# $\lim \sup$ comparison question

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

I want to figure out question 1.6 in Wheenden and Zygmund (2015)

The question is compare 
$\limsup_{k\to\infty} a_k$ with $\limsup(-\infty, a_k)$

(no more condition...)

I think $\limsup a_k \leq \limsup(-\infty, a_k)$

If $\limsup a_k$ is $+\infty$ or $a<\infty$ then equality holds.

If $\limsup a_k$ is $-\infty$ then inequality holds.

But I am not sure whether I'm right or not...

Comment: You wrote $a<\infty$. What is $a$?

Comment: I mean the case which sequence has a finite limit

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that there is no $a$ in your question before you write that $a<\infty$. That doesn't make sense.